# How to check if JSON return is empty with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

```
$.getJSON(url, function(json) {
  var output = '';
  $.each(json, function(i,d) {

    if(d.DESCRIPTION == 'null'){ 
      console.log("Its empty");
    }
    var description = d.DESCRIPTION;
    output += '<tr><td>'+d.NAME+'</td><td>'+'<tr><td>'+d.DESCRIPTION+'</td><td>';
  });
});
```

I tried adding the

```
if(d.DESCRIPTION == 'null'){ console.log("Its empty");
```

to check if the object returned is empty, but it doesn't work.

Can someone explain to me what's wrong with this?

Comment: If you upgrade to jQuery 1.9, it will properly go to the error callback if a json string is not returned.

Comment: If you instead want to check if an object of the array contains empty data, we would need to see exactly what is being returned in your json string as it may be different depending on server-side language and your method of generating json.

Comment: @KevinB all I get back is a text "null" on console

Comment: @adeneo tried it. Doesn't work =/

Comment: @BaconJuice Where in the console? the console has many different sections and i don't see a console.log() that would produce null. is the responseText for the request `"null"`? or is it `""`

Comment: This may be one of the stupider things I've asked, but wouldn't `json` be null before `d` is?

Comment: @KevinB sorry the response text in the console is actually []  just that. again sorry I was a bit confused when I said null

Comment: u should change correct answere

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Just test if the array is empty.

```
$.getJSON(url,function(json){
    if ( json.length == 0 ) {
        console.log("NO DATA!")
    }
});
```

Comment: There is no "length" property JSON Object has so if you get response with not an Array instance you will end up having "NO DATA!" message all the time even if object is not acctualy empty. How this answer ended up approved and with got more reputation than a CORRECT answer below from Mr. Arun Pratap Singh is a mistery for me.

Comment: @Soul_man Right, but in this case it was clearly an array. *"@KevinB sorry the response text in the console is actually [] just that."*

Comment: In my case length is undefined

Comment: @Mo.Ashfaq Then you don't have an array. What do you have?

Comment: When I am performing JSON.stringify on my response, I just get {}

Comment: @amit_kumar  yes it does.

Answer (score 76):

Below code(**jQuery.isEmptyObject(anyObject)** function is already provided) works perfectly fine, no need to write one of your own.

```
   // works for any Object Including JSON(key value pair) or Array.
  //  var arr = [];
  //  var jsonObj = {};
    if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(anyObjectIncludingJSON))
    {
       console.log("Empty Object");
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

```
if (!json[0]) alert("JSON empty");
```

Comment: Hi Justin, it's better to provide some explanation along with your code, than the asker will understand why that particular code works.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. Can you please explain what is happening? Thanks!

Comment: It's checking to see if the first object exists. If JSON has anything, there will be a first object.

Comment: this will only work with array's but not with key value object's  ex. var someJSON = {'name': 'Justin Levene'}

Answer (score 0):

You can use $.isEmptyObject(json)

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject

Comment: This is more or less just repeating [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20262434).

Answer (score -3):

```
$.getJSON(url,function(json){
if ( json.length == 0 ) 
{
console.log("NO !")
}
});
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please check out [how to write good answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7656). Also, this question has been answered a long time ago, we'll be glad if you devote your time to more [recent questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions).