# Can't check an empty JSON key: value pair

Tags: javascript, json

I've tried several answers posted in the site like:

[How to check if JSON return is empty with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345761/how-to-check-if-json-return-is-empty-with-jquery)

And no one is working for me.

```
 xhr.onload = function(){
              detalles = xhr.responseText;
              console.log("log : "+detalles);
   ....
   }
```

Console output:

```
log : [0]
```

Firefox debugger network tab shows JSON 0: 0

Any help provided will be much appreciated.

EDIT - Adding some more code to extend the context

```
xhr.onload = function(){
                  detalles = xhr.responseText;
                  console.log(detalles);

                    if((!$.trim(detalles))||($.isEmptyObject(detalles))||(!detalles[0])){
                        console.log("ok");
                        $("#graficohist").html("No info available");
                        triggerLoader();
                    }
```

Comment: @Salman here is the console output:









[0]

Comment: @Salman xhr is the method I use instead of jquery AJAX (XML HTTP REQUEST).

Answer (score 2):

You can simply make a function to test in the object is empty

```
var myObj = {"key" : "value"};
checkEmptyJson = function(myObj){
var count = 0;
for(var key in myObj){
count++;
break;
}
 if(count == 0){
  return false; // object is empty
 }else{
  return true; // object is not empty
 }
}
var result = checkEmptyJson(myObj);
console.log(result);
```

In your context we can use it as

```
hasDetallesData =  checkEmptyJson(detalles); // true if Detalles has data
```

Comment: This is a good solution but I believe there should be a one liner or simpler method to retrieve a boolean whenever the JSON response is null and I can't find it. Nevertheless I'll try and test your solution. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to try [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp)

```
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
```

to convert your json to a javascript object, and then you can make a print it with

```
console.log(obj)
```

to see what you have inside the `obj`

Comment: Will try it and let you know. Thanks again!